# How to change the search bar default (i.e. php programmer) in osclass bender theme?

Tags: themes, searchbar, osclass

I am having trouble changing the search bar default on osclass bender theme from the default (i.e. PHP programmer)

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what exactly you are having trouble with?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Translate your theme.po file or find it on header.php file